# I can run docker in a directory?

Tags: linux, docker

Have a docker binaries, i run dockerd in /home/user/docker/ using a specific pid path in /home/user/docker/docker.pid but have an error: `mkdir /var/lib/docker: permission denied`. Howto set use specific lib directory? by example `/home/user/docker/lib/`. Need execute a docker instance without root privilegies and only write all files in specific directory. Need execute the docker without linux files structure in main host.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker requires root to run, it is modifying mount points, networking stacks, and other namespaces that cannot be done without root access. It's also a sysadmin level too that effectively gives root access to users that have access to the daemon.